# Controller unable to access Module Angularjs MVC vs 2013

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, module, defined

I am getting `Error : Reference Error: myAppmd is not defined, when running the application`

I have created `app.js` in Script folder of MVC project

```
var myAppmd = angular.module("myApp", []);
```

Controller "name = HomeController" file is stored in `~/Scripts/angularScripts` folder. Code of controller is below

```
 myAppmd.controller("IndexCtrl",  function ()
    {
        $scope.students
        {
            LoginID,  LPassword;
        }

        $scope.submitForm = function($scope)
        {

        }
    }
    )
```

The Bundle file is configured as :

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angularz").IncludeDirectory(
"~/Scripts/angularScripts","*.js",true).Include("~/Scripts/app.js"));
```

In the `_layout.cshtml`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angularz")
....
```

The `Index.cshtml` file code is below

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

    <h2>Welcome to Students Screen/h2>
        <div>
        <form name="frmStudents" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="IndexCtrl">
            <input name="LoginID" type="text" class="col col-lg-4" ng-model="LoginID" value="{{LoginID}}" required />
            <input name="LPassword" type="password" class="col col-lg-4" ng-model="LPassword" value="{{LPassword}}" required />

            <input type="submit" value="Login" ng-click="submitForm()" ng-disabled="$invalid" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your controller is sitting in a separate file you need to get a reference to the app in that file before using it. Note that defining `myAppmd` in app doesn't make it global.

Long story short change your controller code from:

```
myAppmd.controller("IndexCtrl",  function ()
```

To:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller("IndexCtrl",  function ()
```

Comment: Thanks yasir, But If I have to add module in all controller file then what is the benefit to create separate Module file. The idea of separation is to remove redundancy.

Comment: Nope, the benefit of having multiple files is that you don't end up having a large file containing all the code of all of your controllers which can be quite annoying trying to find a bug inside.